# Cordova plugin doesn't work for the first time trigger

Tags: javascript, cordova

I got a strange problem with cordova plugin on iOS.

My cordova plugins (device,network status,wechat ) didn't work when I touch the button to call the plugin , but the plugin will work when I press the home button or pull down the notification bar.

The order is 
Call plugin (nothing happened )-->press home button or pull down Notification Center --> plugin runs

From debug I found that the native code didn't run for the first time trigger the plugin,but it will run automatically when I leave the app .

I'm using Cordova 6.1.1 ,Cordova-iOS 4.1.1, all the plugin have updated to the latest. And the app runs well on android.

My project is using framework 7 and require JS.
It's there anyway to fix that problem?

Comment: try `fastclick` js  [read](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)